# how to create account for application in cyberark password vault

Tags: passwordvault, cyber-ark

i am new to Cyber-Ark password vault and my try is to integrate artifactory with cyber-ark for some generic accounts whose passwords should be stored in the vault.

may i know the exact proess to get it created. We have one safe and i tried to create a safe account as below.

```
curl -k --location --request POST "https://mypw.net/API/AccountGroups/" \
  --header "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{
  \"GroupName\":\"AccountGroup01\",
  \"Safe\":\"MY_SAFE\"
}"
```

its just executed and didnt give any error as well.. Hope it got created. But when i tried to verify this,

```
curl -k --location --request GET "https:/mypw.net/PasswordVault/API/AccountGroups?Safe=MY_SAFE" \
  --header "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

getting error as

```
{"ErrorCode":"PASWS006E","ErrorMessage":"The session token is missing, invalid or expired."}
```

is there any mistake which i am doing here and is there any way to get the web access on this to verify also ?

Comment: Are you sure the token is valid? Did you succeed in retrieving information with this token? Did you create the account group in your safe?

Comment: The error is about the session token. May be invalid or expired. Yes if the safe creation is successful it just doesn't return anything. http status code return is success (201).